# My player sprite keeps on disappearing if it lands on the platform

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to build my first Platformer Game. So far, I have make moving left and right but unfortunately, I have encountered a error that I have not been able to fix when I implemented collisions and gravity. My player keeps on dissolving like spider man if it lands on the platform. The character is still existent, and lands on the platform, but unfortunately, he becomes invisible. There is no error message, and I suspect is has to do with the collision check.

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(object, allPlatforms, False)
    if hits:
        object.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        object.vy = 0

    print(object.rect.midbottom)
```

It prints out the Players location in the code, and the player is still existent and movable, but it just doesn't show. Is there something that I did that makes the character vanish?

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH  = 500
HEIGHT = 400
FPS = 30


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

playerImage = "blockBandit/BlockBandit.png"

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image = pygame.image.load(playerImage).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y




pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Block Bandit")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

allPlatforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

p1 = Platform(0, HEIGHT - 40, WIDTH, 40)
all_sprites.add(p1)
allPlatforms.add(p1)


def moveCharacter(object):

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        object.vx += -2
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        object.vx += 2

    object.vx = object.vx * 0.9

    if (abs(object.vx) < 1):
        object.vx = 0

    if (abs(object.vx) > 10):
        if(object.vx < 0):
            object.vx = -10
        else:
            object.vx = 10

    object.vy = object.vy + 1

    object.rect.x += object.vx
    object.rect.y += object.vy

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(object, allPlatforms, False)
    if hits:
        object.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
        object.vy = 0

    print(object.rect.midbottom)

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    moveCharacter(player)
    #Update State
    all_sprites.update()

    #Render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    #screen.blit(player.icon, (20, 40))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `y` attribute of the rect is the same as the `top` coordinate, so you're setting the top of the player sprite to the top of the platform sprite here `object.rect.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1`. And if the platform comes later in the sprite group, it will be blitted after the player and the player won't be visible.

Just change that line to `object.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top + 1`.